# Using ssh to execute a remote script in the background doesn't exit immediately

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

Why the follow ssh command doesn't exit immediately. Instead, it will exit after 1m

`ssh -vvv <usr>@<ip> 'sh -c "sleep 60 &"'`

But I do tell shell to run sleep command in the background, I don't know why

Comment: try `ssh -vvv <usr>@<ip> 'sh -c "sleep 60 &" &>/dev/null </dev/null'`

Comment: Also, use `-T` option to disable pseudo-tty allocation like `ssh -T ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the file descriptors opened by the `sh` process are indirectly connected to your ssh session's tty.
`sleep` command does not take anything on `stdin` not does it send anything back to `stdout/stderr`. However, the FDs inherited from `sh` are still open.

The way out is to close those FDs by ip/op/err redirection.

```
ssh -vvv <usr>@<ip> 'sh -c "sleep 60 &" &>/dev/null </dev/null'
```

Comment: Thanks, it really works. But the `sh` process should be exited immediately. Why `sshd` doesn't tell client to exit when it's child process exited.